# Angular.js Method duplication in controller when using service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, proxy, controller

I've created a `BookService` that is used for storing (`add`), getting (`getAll`) and removing (`remove`) books. Now I want to use this BookService inside my controller to publish some methods that I can later use in my view. My controller looks like the following:

```
app.controller('BookController', ['BookService', '$scope', function(BookService, $scope) {

  $scope.addBook = function() { BookService.add(); }
  $scope.getAllBooks = function() { BookService.getAll(); } 
  $scope.removeBook = function() { BookService.remove(); }

}]);
```

As you can see, the controller is just a proxy that forwards the method calls to the service. Is this in general bad practice? And is there a better way to solve that using `Angular.js`? Calling the service directly from the view without a controller seems, to me like a bigger problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have shown is not bad practice; it is in fact recommended that you abstract resource management logic (like adding, removing and finding resources of the same type) into a separate service, for organization and maintainability and reusability purposes.

I do understand from your example how the controller seems to be just a proxy to the service though, and why you would think it's repetitive and possibly redundant. Let me expand on your example to see if I can explain the reasons for abstracting the logic. In doing so, let's consider only the adding operation, even though the logic would apply to others as well.

Reason 1: adding a book (or any resource for that matter) in a web app is usually more complicated than just a `bookService.add()` call. It requires having some sort of form to enter the details, a submit button to handle the actual request, possible massaging of the entered data, adding new fields like time stamps and author ids, and persisting to some data storage. The first two or three of those steps would be applicable to the screen or view from which you are adding, so it makes sense to put that in a controller (the view model), whereas the rest of the steps should go into the generic service.

Now say you have another screen where you see a friend's list of books and you can add it to your list by selecting a book. In that case, the controller logic for that view's controller will differ from the previous example, but the service steps will still be identical, and thus do not need to be duplicated since the service can be injected into both controllers.

That's a big win.

Example 2: let's say you've already split the code between controller and service as describe in example 1 above. Then you decide that your data storage needs have changed and now you want to update your logic to save to a different database system. Now instead of having to change all the controllers, you just change your services and the everything works.

This is also a really big win.

Answer (score 2):

**Best Practice**

From what I can see this is perfectly good practice, I'm assuming that you're using `$scope` here to bind these services to a button or something similar. The Idea of using a factory or a service is to create some well organised reusable code that you can then instantiate in your controller exactly like you have done.

Controllers can get quite complex so moving basic functionality to your service is the best thing to do. In your case you have a relatively simple controller so you may not see the benefit of coding in this way. But I assure you that as your code base grows you will be required to code like this just to keep things readable.

**Note**

Just as an extra note I've added a data process that you might take with an example of a database request

```
database > API > service/factory > controller > view
```

This would be the correct path to take when requesting something from a database.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you'ved done this correctly.  Just keep in mind that as you scaled up your app in complexity, you'll want to have isolated scopes, (and) decomposition into component directives.  Each directive will have its own controller and template fragment.